# Query for retrieving the chosen data

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Im not good in querying. I would like to ask if this query works.
I want to retrieve starttime, endtime and sessioncost from the table SESSION of my database. my program will be an autorun. IT MEANS THAT ID SHOULD BE SELECTED AUTOMATICALLY WHEN IT RUNS.

```
Dim sql As String = "select STARTTIME, ENDTIME, SESSIONCOST from SESSIONS where CLIENTID =  (?)"
```

I cant post the image because it requires more than 10 reputation. Im sorry.. If you have a better code/query, I appreciate your help. :)
thank you so much for your feedback..

Comment: you mean you want to display it randomly with CLIENTID

Comment: not randomly @Rafee. If this query problem solve, the next step would be the automation selection of the data that will be retrieving.

Comment: can you be more specific, or upload image, do you want the latest updated row from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First count CLIENTID into one variable

sql query for count

```
select count(ClIENTID) from SESSIONS;
```

now store this count value into some variable

```
Dim count_variable As Integer

Dim MyValue As Integer
Randomize   ' Initialize random-number generator.
MyValue = CInt(Int((count_variable * Rnd()) + 1))
```

Now once you get the random value

```
Dim sql As String = "select STARTTIME, ENDTIME, SESSIONCOST from SESSIONS where CLIENTID = MyValue"
```

By this way you can get random results within the count of clientids

Comment: and you check out for randomization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: thank you.. I would like to clarify that this retrieval of data will not be in random. I would like to retrieve the Starttime, endtime and sessioncost values from the rows of the table SESSION.. and display the output in console. ive used console application in VB.NET @Rafee

Comment: i would like to ask about your code. I dont want to use the randomize. I want to display all the data from the tbl_SESSION and retrieve the STARTTIME, ENDTIME AND SESSIONCOST values sequentially. Pls i need help..

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Oledb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Dim con1 As New SqlConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Sql.12.0;Data     Source=giveyourdatabaselocation")
con1.Open()
Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("select STARTTIME, ENDTIME AND SESSIONCOST from tbl_SESSION", con1)

Dim ada1 As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
Dim ds1 As New DataSet
ada1.Fill(ds1)
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)

con1.Close()
```

//Note all the data will be displayed in Datagridview

//And if you want to display in diffferent textboxes you can write the below code

```
Dim con1 As New SqlConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Sql.12.0;Data Source=giveyourdatabaselocation")
con1.Open()
Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("select STARTTIME, ENDTIME AND SESSIONCOST from tbl_SESSION", con1)

Dim dr3 As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)

While dr3.Read
    TextBox1.Text = dr3.GetValue(0).ToString()
    TextBox2.Text = dr3.GetValue(1).ToString()
    TextBox3.Text = dr3.GetValue(2).ToString()
End While

con1.Close()
```

let me know, what you are looking out more